# I need help figuring out to create an automated food ordering system

Tags: python

I'm currently making a food ordering system for my school project. Simple enough.

Then, I was given an extra task to create a program where the system automatically creates an order based on your order history and/or profiler such as allergy, vegetarian, and more.

I don't need a complete code but just an idea of how to make such a program possible. I'm using Python in case you're wondering.

Comment: What level of Python do you know? You could make use of object-oriented programming to hold student data.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the program is intended to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One idea:
If it's given that you have past order history from a customer, you could create a Student object that holds what they ordered in the past. Then you can reference the most common items they ordered and display a recommendation.

Also, it's not very clear what you're asking for. Are you trying to make a user interface with selections, or just text input into a terminal? What level of python do you know?

As you'll find on this website, precise details matter when it comes to code solutions, so the more detail the question has, the better the answer and the greater the chance someone can have a really good solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The system would have a simple graphical user interface with selections.